# javascript in oracle ADF jsf page

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

How can I add java script file to inline or footer in jsf ADF Oracle?

I typically use IE conditional comments to fix the IE issues. But there are more ways than the conditional like the one I use below:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

And how can I apply these kind of conditions in Oracle ADF?

Answer (score 1):

Here a very easy example on how to use java script in ADF.
http://sameh-nassar.blogspot.be/2010/02/javascript-functions-sample.html